# How to get buttons shown in a different column than your text in html

Tags: css, html

I need the buttons to be in a different column than the text. But i don't want the buttons to have a margin right because then the buttons would not be in a straight line

```
<h1 id="h1" style="float:left;margin:0"></h1>
<a href="#" id="Btn" class="button">Btn</a>

<h1 id="h2" style="float:left;margin:0"></h1>
<a href="#" id="Btn2" class="button">Btn2</a>

<h1 id="h3" style="float:left;margin:0"></h1>
<a href="#" id="Btn2" class="button">Btn3</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding your buttons in a table

```
    <table><tr><td>
    <h1 id="h1" style="float:left;margin:0">//Some text here</h1></td><td>
    <a href="#" id="Btn" class="button">Btn</a> </td></tr>

    <tr><td>
    <h1 id="h2" style="float:left;margin:0">//Some text here</h1></td><td>
    <a href="#" id="Btn2" class="button">Btn2</a></td></tr>

    <tr><td>
    <h1 id="h3" style="float:left;margin:0">//Some text here</h1></td><td>
    <a href="#" id="Btn2" class="button">Btn3</a></td></tr>

    </table>
```

Add your text in `//Some Text Here`. The above code gives a perfectly aligned vertical buttons.If you want horizontally aligned, then remove`<td>` tags where needed.

Comment: what if my headlines are bigger then the button?and im using images for the button which makes it go more to the top then it is not quite on the same line with the headline anymore do you have a solution for that ?

Comment: If you can show me how your page actually looks in any way with the code, I will try to give you the simplest solution for your problem. Currently I cannot say anything since the information is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping each header (h1) and button into div (that will show them each in new line) and adding `display: inline` to h1.

```
<div>
  <h1 id="h1">TEXT</h1>
  <a href="#" id="Btn" class="button">Btn</a>
</div>

<div>
  <h1 id="h2">TEXT</h1>
  <a href="#" id="Btn2" class="button">Btn2</a>
</div>

<div>
  <h1 id="h3">TEXT</h1>
  <a href="#" id="Btn2" class="button">Btn3</a>
</div>

h1 {
  display: inline;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/06aae3gq/

Answer (score 0):

in addition to @Paul 's answer you can add css to TD

https://jsfiddle.net/maky/6x23gL1p/1/

```
td {
  width: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is just a standard grid to put stuff in columns.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column column-1">
        <h1>text</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="column column-2">
        <a href="#" class="button">Btn</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column column-1">
        <h1>text</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="column column-2">
        <a href="#" class="button">Btn</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then in your style:

```
<style>
    /* .row now is just a simple clearfix */
    .row:before,
    .row:after {
        content: " ";
        display: table;
    }
    .row:after {
        clear: both;
    }
    .column
    {
        float: left;
    }
    .column-1,
    .column-2
    {
        width: 200px;
    }
</style>
```

in response to the other examples:

- inlining the H1 will not give it the same width
- tables are 1993, only use them for tabular data